# How to generate schema diagram from POCOs

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm learning EF Core with SQL Server and trying to generate schema diagram among POCOs. I implemented the code-first approach and want to get a schema diagram shows each entity and relations. 
I tried to generate the schema from Database Management Studio, but it doesn't contain navigation properties information. So, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that usually by creating a physical database using `dotnet ef database update` or other migration method and then using your db provider to reverse engineer the schema for you. For example, if you use SQL server, there is an option to create database schema in the SQL Management Studio UI. Other DBMS will likely have similar options.

Comment: I don't want SQL Server table diagrams but entities diagram including navigation properties

Comment: why is this marked as the accepted answer, when the OP commented that this isn't what he wants?  I found this question here by googling this very issue - and don't understand this response's accepted status.